# Django OperationalError: missing table; migration does not recognize missing table

Tags: django, database, sqlite, migration

I'm having trouble in Django 1.7, I am trying to save a user to a table, but I'm getting an error that the table does not exist.

Here is the code I'm executing:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth import BACKEND_SESSION_KEY, SESSION_KEY, get_user_model
User = get_user_model()
from django.contrib.sessions.backends.db import SessionStore
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand
class Command(BaseCommand):

    def handle(self, email, *_, **__):

        session_key = create_pre_authenticated_session(email)
        self.stdout.write(session_key)


def create_pre_authenticated_session(email):
    user = User.objects.create(email=email)
    session = SessionStore()
    session[SESSION_KEY] = user.pk
    session[BACKEND_SESSION_KEY] = settings.AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS[0]
    session.save()
    return session.session_key
```

However, at

```
    user = User.objects.create(email=email)
```

I get an **Error** message :

```
 django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: accounts_user
```

Here is the user model at accounts/models.py that I'm trying to use to build the table:

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone

class User(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField(primary_key=True)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ()
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'

    def is_authenticated(self):
        return True
```

I've run sqlmigrate against this migration with **`'manage.py accounts 0001.initial'`** and I have gotten the correct create table SQL back, but running **`'manage.py migrate'`** gives me the following :

```
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: sessions, admin, lists, contenttypes, accounts, auth
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.
```

The migration is just the result of running 'makemigration' from the shell, no custom code. I do see accounts listed in the included applications, but the migration isn't being ran, so my site is in an odd spot where Django says the table is missing when I try to use it, but Django says it exists when I try to run the migration to create it.
 Why does Django erroneously think that the table already exists when I can look at the database and see that it doesn't?

Comment: Try running `python manage.py makemigrations --app-name` before running `python manage.py migrate`// or check if you have faked the previous `migrate` process

Comment: You're working the the Test-Driven Design book by Harry Percival right? I'm running into the exact same problem. We must have missed a step somewhere.

Comment: Eric: I figured out a solution that worked for me. Turns out I didn't miss a step, but the place where he places his sql file is different from where Django naturally creates it. Django's base sqlite file is under src/db.sqlite3.  However, if you look under src/superlists/db.sqlite3, you'll find that another sqlite file was created as per the path given by the settings for BASE_DIR. I suspect the discrepancy is a result of the book using an older version of Django

Comment: How do you serve your Django app? Are you sure you `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` are the same in both manage.py & web server?

Answer (score 2):

@user856358  Your comment about the other sqlite file seems like the root cause.  I encountered the same error, and it was resolved by removing that file and running another migration.  In my case, the file was located as specified in `settings.py`:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '../database/db.sqlite3'),
    }
}
```

By removing the .sqlite3 file there, I was able to successfully run the migration and resolve the no-such-table error...

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: accounts_user
$ rm ../database/db.sqlite3 
$ python3 manage.py migrate
```