# OperationalError: no such table (sqlite)

Tags: django

Was having a problem with my database so I deleted it along with all of my migrations folders (I'm using Djano 1.7).

After that, I ran the following commands

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

and all of my migrations appear to run correctly

but when I try to create a superuser I get the error `OperationalError: no such table: accounts_myuser`

What gives? And how do I troubleshoot?

Comment: Are all your apps using the django 1.7 migrations? It seems your `accounts` app is not. Try running `syncdb`.

Comment: May be related (see comments): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27814144/django-operationalerror-missing-table-migration-does-not-recognize-missing-tab

Comment: @BurhanKhalid that did the trick.  Still not entirely sure why.  The only external app I'm using is AllAuth

Answer (score 0):

Run this command and post its contents in comment.

```
python manage.py sqlmigrate
```

Check the following-:

1. Add 'django.contrib.admin' to the INSTALLED_APPS setting.
2. Make sure INSTALLED_APPS contains 'django.contrib.auth', 'django.contrib.contenttypes', 'django.contrib.messages' and 'django.contrib.sessions'.
3. Make sure MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES contains 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware', 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware', 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware' and 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware'.

Then execute

1)python manage.py makemigrations

2) python manage.py migrate